# Does a child tear Kriyah at the Kosel?

Tags: halacha, clothing, mourning-aveilus, minor-katan-child, kotel-western-wall

Does a kid under Bar/Bas Mitzva have to tear Kriya when they go to the Kosel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. From [one parent who actually observed a bat mitzva by having her daughter tear for the first time](http://www.ou.org/jewish_action/03/2010/making_a_meaningful_bat_mitzvah/):

> [Mishnah Berurah, Orach Chaim 561:17](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.94). In fact, children might be forbidden
>   to tear their clothes because of ba’al tashchit, the prohibition against wanton waste! See, for a related analysis, [Minchat Chinuch 264:34](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37519&st=&pgnum=154)<sup>*</sup> (Machon Yerushalayim edition, [Netanya, 5748]).

(Not that I'm commenting on whether it's a good idea to celebrate a bar/bat mitzva by an act of mourning; that's a different question but not one that can be answered in this forum.)

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>264:9 in the linked edition from HebrewBooks.org</sub>